# Element retains on-hover property of parent, when hover over itself and not parent

Tags: html, css

```css
.filename-display {
    padding: 0 2px 0 7px
}

.filename-display:hover~.thumb-list-view {
    display: block;
}

.thumb-list-view {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -90px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.thumb-list-view img {
    height: 90px!important;
    width: 120px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-ellipsis filename-display">Material Name</div>
<div class="thumb-list-view thumb-list-view-22" style="margin-top: 125px;">
 <img class="thumb-img" ng-src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2764438/389965999/stock-vector-vector-laptop-personal-computer-in-flat-style-desktop-computer-computer-icon-isolated-on-389965999.jpg" src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2764438/389965999/stock-vector-vector-laptop-personal-computer-in-flat-style-desktop-computer-computer-icon-isolated-on-389965999.jpg">
</div>
```

With this code I show a thumb image below the filename-display div when user hovers over the name. And as soon as you remove the mouse from the name the image is hidden. The issue arises when you hover over the name and scroll down, where it takes a split second to hide the image. Was just wondering if that split second is the lag in DOM updation or this lag can be eliminated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a chaining issue while you are trying to display image on hover. There is no class as .material-name but still used to apply hover event. Try removing it. It works as expected

```css
.material-list .filename-display {
    padding: 0 2px 0 7px
}

.filename-display:hover~.thumb-list-view {
    display: block;
}

.thumb-list-view {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -90px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 120px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.thumb-list-view img {
    height: 90px!important;
    width: 120px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-ellipsis filename-display">Material Name</div>
<div class="thumb-list-view thumb-list-view-22" style="margin-top: 125px;">
 <img class="thumb-img" ng-if="material.material_type === msvm.materialConfig.materialType.fabric" ng-src="http://10.127.22.171:8080/DesignPortal/mos/app/60031755_front_tile.jpg" dp-image-fallback-src="img/mos/apparel/fabric/type-na/woven.jpg" src="img/mos/apparel/fabric/type-na/woven.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: There's no issue when you take the mouse out of the material name, the image vanishes instantly, but then you keep your cursor still and scroll down, the images scrolls up and takes some time to disappear. And the same HTML when placed inside an ng-repeat, makes the images take some time before being hidden.